# install pack for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04

I have to install a package (J-Link: https://www.segger.com/jlink-software.html) into Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Latest 64 bit (4.1.0-x86_64-linode59)), but I am not sure which one I should install:

- DEB Installer 64-bit version
- RPM Installer 64-bit version
- TGZ archive 64-bit version

Comment: There is a sister site for Linux questions, SO is all about programming.

Comment: You should actually not download any packages for installation at all, except in very special cases, since you never know what those packages actually contain. Are you really sure that the package you require is not offered in the official repositories which would make the question obsolete? Or some adequate alternative? Keep in mind your risk: you hand over administrative access to your system to someone you do not know.

Comment: segger: https://www.segger.com/jlink-software.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three are possible, but 
It is probably easiest to install the .deb, assuming it is appropriate for your operating system.

---

To check the integrity of the deb **before installing**:

```
md5sum PACKAGE.deb
```

and make sure the output matches the md5sum reported on the website from which you downloaded the deb.

Then to install the deb:

```
dpkg -i PACKAGE.deb
```